# HP Laserjet M1136 MFP in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing, hp, laserjet

My *HP Laserjet M1136 MFP* used to work well in Ubuntu 15.10 with hplip. After an update it stopped working, but still showed the message that pages were printed successfully.

I upgraded the system to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it still doesn't work, though the printer was detected and installed without any trouble. While scanning it shows the message "device I/O error".

The `lsusb` output is

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:042a Hewlett-Packard LaserJet M1132 MFP
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0042 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

HP device manager also can't help, its test print shows the same message.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem and after a massive search found this tip
and succeeded. If there are still problems, try this:

1. Make sure that the HP LaserJet M1132 MFP is connected to the computer and power is turned on!
2. Open a terminal
3. Run the following command in the terminal

sudo hp-setup -i

4. Go through the setup process…
5. At some point, the program wants to download a proprietary binary file (hp-plugin) and that can take a couple of minutes to start downloading – be patient, it will start!
6. Once the setup has finished, printing should work without any problems…

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the hplip driver

> sudo apt-get purge --remove hplip
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove
>
> sudo apt-get install hplip

And set up your printer again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is the same. It shows the same message that the print job has been completed, without any movement.

Answer (score -1):

maybe the command `hp-doctor` can help...

HP Smart Install is a service running on firmware which makes printer to appear as "Mass Storage Devices" when connected via USB cable. This is to install the minimal printer software from flash memory of printer. This service needs to be disabled on linux in order to have the device function as a printer.

Run hp-doctor script. It will notify you if there is a Smart Install device connected and prompt you for disabling the same.

Source: http://hplipopensource.com/node/367